# Grid View Column Will Not Word Wrap

Tags: asp.net

I've made a gridview and I need the columns width ratios to be exact.  Here's my code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="table" DataSourceID="Data" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray" ShowHeader="false" 
                            DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" >

                            <Columns>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="date" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="beltStatus" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberOfBelts" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="returnDate" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="prepaidAmount" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="checkNumber" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-CssClass="fixedWidth" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberOfModsFiveStar" ItemStyle-Width="5%"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberOfModsCanada" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberOfBuckles" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="numberOfBags" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="customerName" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-CssClass="fixedWidth" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="state" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />

                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["historyLog"] + "?table=mos&id=" + Eval("ID") %>' 
                                            Text='<%# Eval("lastChangedByUser") + " - " + Eval("lastChangeTime") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

fixed width css:

```
.fixedWidth
{
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

Customer Name is almost always longer than the column width.  I want the text to drop down to the next line.  Instead it does this:

[image: img]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have `white-space: nowrap` specified somewhere else withing your CSS.  Trying adding: `white-space: normal` to your fixedWidth CSS class.  If that doesn't work, open Chrome right-click on the table cell, and say "inspect element".  This will open the Chrome dev tools and there will be a "styles" tab, which will show you how the styles are being applied.  You can also dynamically change the values for the styles within the Chrome dev tools and check the results.

Comment: This is helpful as an alternative to wordbreak: break-all which makes things look weird if on a small enough screen because it breaks down by letter....whitespace: normal instead allows it to break but only down to the word level.